# R - identify duplicates based on two columns, find values, and delete cases with specific value

Tags: r, filter, duplicates

I'm analysing a database with ecological data. Here is a example:

```
df <- data.frame(observationID = c("06a4dcc1-a2c1-f1a9-3964-4374c3a26e2a","b8431c2b-fa18-42bf-b2c9-3dc23d308b44","b8431c2b-fa18-42bf-b2c9-3dc23d308b44","ff8a8b93-f307-4695-ad95-1915c2c46c60","ff8a8b93-f307-4695-ad95-1915c2c46c60","c240564d-a100-4cdb-8a81-8ac197a45e8b","c240564d-a100-4cdb-8a81-8ac197a45e8b","f0a18902-fd16-4d82-bc3a-10bd47454dff","f0a18902-fd16-4d82-bc3a-10bd47454dff","f0a18902-fd16-4d82-bc3a-10bd47454dff"),
               animalVernacularName = c("wild boar","Horse","Horse","Horse","Horse","Common Buzzard","Common Buzzard","wild boar","wild boar","Fox"),
               behav = c("1","1","2","1","2","1","1","1","1","2"),
               value = c("Passing","Interest","Intraspecific interaction","Interest","Intraspecific interaction","Interest","Intraspecific interaction","Eating","Intraspecific interaction","Eating"))
```

I want to identify duplicates based on two variables ('observationID' & 'behav'), then find the 'observationID'-value of these duplicates, and delete all cases with this 'observationID'-value. Not only one of the two duplicates, but all cases with the 'observationID' (there can be more cases than only the duplicates). I need to delete all cases with this 'observationID', because the entire observation (consisting of multiple cases) is incorrectly entered.

It's not a problem to only identify the duplicates, but it is to also have R give me the 'observationID'-value of these duplicates.

There are simple ways of finding duplicates in two columns. For example, I've tried

```
dupe <- duplicated(df[c("observationID","behav")])
```

Here it identifies the duplicates, but I don't see an option of how to find the corresponding 'observationID'-value.

By doing this

```
test <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = behav, values_from = value, names_prefix = "behav", values_fn = list(value = length))
```

I do find the duplicates and see the corresponding 'observationID', but I can't find a way of having R return these values, so I can delete the observations.

I'm looking for a way to have R return to me a list of 'observationID'-values of the duplicates found based on the columns 'observationID' & 'behav'. In this example I'm looking for a way to delete all cases with 'observationID':

```
"c240564d-a100-4cdb-8a81-8ac197a45e8b"
"f0a18902-fd16-4d82-bc3a-10bd47454dff"
```

Then I can use this list of for a filter() for my dataset.

So ultimately, i hope to have the following result.

```
df_result <- data.frame(observationID = c("06a4dcc1-a2c1-f1a9-3964-4374c3a26e2a","b8431c2b-fa18-42bf-b2c9-3dc23d308b44","b8431c2b-fa18-42bf-b2c9-3dc23d308b44","ff8a8b93-f307-4695-ad95-1915c2c46c60","ff8a8b93-f307-4695-ad95-1915c2c46c60"),
             animalVernacularName = c("wild boar","Horse","Horse","Horse","Horse"),
             behav = c("1","1","2","1","2"),
             value = c("Passing","Interest","Intraspecific interaction","Interest","Intraspecific interaction"))
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df$observationID[dupe]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options.

```r
df[ ! df$observationID %in% df$observationID[dupe], ]
#                          observationID animalVernacularName behav
# 1 06a4dcc1-a2c1-f1a9-3964-4374c3a26e2a            wild boar     1
# 2 b8431c2b-fa18-42bf-b2c9-3dc23d308b44                Horse     1
# 3 b8431c2b-fa18-42bf-b2c9-3dc23d308b44                Horse     2
# 4 ff8a8b93-f307-4695-ad95-1915c2c46c60                Horse     1
# 5 ff8a8b93-f307-4695-ad95-1915c2c46c60                Horse     2
#                       value
# 1                   Passing
# 2                  Interest
# 3 Intraspecific interaction
# 4                  Interest
# 5 Intraspecific interaction

### or
dplyr::anti_join(df, df[dupe,"observationID",drop=FALSE], by = "observationID")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. The answers are very short, simple and clean. I looked into them and I understand how it works. Again I've learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     filter(!observationID %in% observationID[dupe])
```